# Event.observe() not working; ProtoytypeJS library

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I have this code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js">    </script>
        <script>
            Event.observe('clickme', 'click', function(event) {
                alert('clicked');
            });

            Event.observe('uploadme', 'change', function(event) {
                alert('hola');
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insertimage.php" method="post" name="changer">
            <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10240000" type="hidden">
            <input id="uploadme"  type="file">
            <input type="button"  id="clickme" value="Upload Stuff!" />
            <input id="sub" type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is not working. I am unable to get alert for anything. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the script just above **body** closing tag, like:

```
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insertimage.php" method="post" name="changer">
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10240000" type="hidden">
<input id="uploadme"  type="file">
<input type="button"  id="clickme" value="Upload Stuff!" />
<input id="sub" type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
Event.observe('clickme', 'click', function(event) {
    alert('clicked');
});
Event.observe('uploadme', 'change', function(event) {
    alert('hola');
});
</script>
</body>
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZU5dF/1/)

Or, if you want to keep the **script** tag inside **head**,other option would be:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    Event.observe('clickme', 'click', function(event) {
        alert('clicked');
    });
    Event.observe('uploadme', 'change', function(event) {
        alert('hola');
    });
});
```